# libGDX Error loading font file - Netbeans

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to load a font in libGDX. But I can't figure out want I do wrong.

Code:

```
white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/white.font"), false);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading font file: fonts/white.font
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.load(BitmapFont.java:657)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(BitmapFont.java:469)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:115)
    at scenes.GameMode.create(GameMode.java:61)
    at scenes.GameMode.<init>(GameMode.java:45)
    at com.circle.game.Circle.create(Circle.java:17)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.load(BitmapFont.java:480)
    ... 7 more
:desktop:run
```

[image: Files]

Comment: The error says "File not found: font/white.font". Your directory seems to be called "fonts", not "font".

Comment: Ok that was an Error but not the Error. I'm still getting the error :( `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading font file: fonts/white.font`

Comment: That is a very different error. It sounds like the file is now found, but can't be loaded for another reason. Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Since you also have a `white.png` file, that makes me think you want to use the [three-argument `BitmapFont` constructor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#BitmapFont-com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle-com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle-boolean-) that takes a font file (specifying glyph positions) as well as an image file (containing the actual glyph images). Could that be it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LibGDX, the **user.dir** property is used for the `Gdx.files.internal(...)` root directory. This property is, unless explicitly changed, set to the directory from which the app was launched.

With that being said, you should move your *assets* folder to your target platform's root dir (desktop for Desktop, android for Android, etc.).

Also, after the first step (Whatever it may be, you should use `assets/fonts/white.font` rather than `fonts/white.font`, as LibGDX does not automatically use the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct.. But
Have you set the working directory of the desktop project?
If not set working directory of desktop project to Android/assets 
Else, it is the error caused by the file itself
which tool did you use to generate the font file? 
Use a tool called BMFont